# How to solve this 'NoneType' object error?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to fix this error for the past couple of hours.  I'm new to python, so it'll probably be an easy fix for you guys.

```
import re, sys, time, string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import logging

class FetchAllSybols(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # URL
        # default m (market) - IN, t (type) - S (stock)
        self.sym_start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/stocks?t=S&m=IN"
        self.sym_page_url = '&b=0'#page
        self.sym_alphanum_search_url = '&s=a' #search alphabet a
        self.sym_full_url = ''
        self.alphabet_str_to_search = string.ascii_lowercase # full alphabet
        self.sym_info = {}
        self.header = "SymbolId,Full Name, Type, Exchange, URL\n" 

    def set_alphabet_in_url(self, alphabet):
        """ 
        Set the alphabet portion of the url by passing the alphabet.
        :param alphbet (str): can be alphabet.
        """
        self.sym_alphanum_search_url = '&s=' + str(alphabet)

    def set_pagenumber_in_url(self, pageno):
        """ 
        Set the page portion of the url by passing the pageno.
        :param pageno (str): page number.
        """
        self.sym_page_url = '&b=' + str(pageno)


    def gen_next_url(self):
        """ 
        Creates the full url necessary for sym scan by joining the search parameter and page no.
        """
        self.sym_full_url =  self.sym_start_url + self.sym_alphanum_search_url + self.sym_page_url    

    def get_data_from_next_page(self):
        self.gen_next_url()
        print ("Fetching data from URL", self.sym_full_url)
        req = urllib2.Request(self.sym_full_url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
        html = None
        counter = 0
        while counter < 10:
            try:
                html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
                logging.error(error.read())
                logging.info("Will try 10 times with 2 seconds sleep")
                time.sleep(2) 
                counter += 1
            else:
                break

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")
        return soup

    def get_all_valid_symbols(self):
        """ 
        Scan all the symbol for one page. The parsing are split into odd and even rows.
        """
        soup = self.get_data_from_next_page()
        table = soup.find_all("div", class_="yui-content")
        table_rows = table[0].find_all('tr')
        for table_row in table_rows:
            if table_row.find('td'):
                if table_row.contents[2].text != 'NaN':
                    self.sym_info[table_row.contents[0].text]=[table_row.contents[1].text,
                                                               table_row.contents[3].text,
                                                               table_row.contents[4].text,
                                                               table_row.a["href"]]

    def get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet(self, alphabet):
        """ 
        Get the total search results based on each search to determine the number of page to scan.
        :param alphabet (int): The total number of page to scan
        """
        self.sym_start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/stocks?t=S&m=IN&r="
        self.sym_page_url = '&b=0'#page
        self.sym_alphanum_search_url = '&s='+alphabet

        soup = self.get_data_from_next_page()
        total_search_str = (str(soup.find_all("div", id="pagination")))

        #Get the number of page
        total_search_qty = re.search('of ([1-9]*\,*[0-9]*).*',total_search_str).group(1)
        total_search_qty = int(total_search_qty.replace(',','', total_search_qty.count(',')))
        final_search_page_count = total_search_qty/20 #20 seach per page.

        return final_search_page_count


    def get_total_sym_for_each_search(self, alphabet):
        """ 
        Scan all the page indicate by the search item.
        The first time search or the first page will get the total number of search.
        Dividing it by 20 results per page will give the number of page to search.
        :param alphabet(str)
        """
        # Get the first page info first
        self.set_pagenumber_in_url(0)
        total_page_to_scan =  self.get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet(alphabet)
        logging.info('Total number of pages to scan: [%d]'% total_page_to_scan)

        # Scan the rest of the page.
        # may need to get time to rest
        for page_no in range(0,total_page_to_scan+1,1):
            self.set_pagenumber_in_url(page_no*20)
            self.gen_next_url()
            logging.info('Scanning page number: [%d] url: [%s]  ' % (page_no, self.sym_full_url))          
            self.get_all_valid_symbols()

    def serach_for_each_alphabet(self):
        """ 
        Sweep through all the alphabets to get the full list of shares.
        """
        for alphabet in self.alphabet_str_to_search:
            logging.info('Searching for : [%s]' % alphabet)
            self.set_alphabet_in_url(alphabet)
            self.get_total_sym_for_each_search(alphabet)

    def dump_into_file(self):
        '''
        Store all symbols into a csv file.
        '''
        f = open('Symbol_Info.csv', 'w')
        f.write(self.header)

        for key in sorted(self.sym_info):
            values = self.sym_info[key]
            sym = key+','
            for value in values:
                sym += str(value) + ','
            sym += '\n'
            f.write(sym)
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(ch)

    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("dump.log")
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(fileHandler)

    f = FetchAllSybols()
    f.alphanum_str_to_search = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    f.serach_for_each_alphabet()
    f.dump_into_file()
```

I've been getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 157, in <module>
    f.serach_for_each_alphabet()
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 122, in serach_for_each_alphabet
    self.get_total_sym_for_each_search(alphabet)
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 104, in get_total_sym_for_each_search
    total_page_to_scan =  self.get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet(alphabet)
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 88, in get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet
    total_search_qty = re.search('of ([1-9]*\,*[0-9]*).*',total_search_str).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I think it has to do with this line but I"m not sure:

```
table = soup.find_all("div", class_="yui-content")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

`total_search_qty = re.search('of ([1-9]*\,*[0-9]*).*',total_search_str)`

in

`get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet`

isn't matching anything so it returns None instead of a `MatchObject`. When you try to use the `.group` method, the interpreter complains that `NoneType` doesn't have any attribute named `group`. This should have been easy to figure out by carefully reading the Traceback. Try to get used to reading this because it will be invaluable for debugging.

So either you need to refine your regex, or if you think that it is some exceptional circumstance you can use exception handling to deal with this gracefully. If it is something that might come up frequently, a simple conditional check to deal with it might be the way to go.